# Confusion with PHP header for Content Disposition

Tags: php, passthru, htmldoc

I have a basic question and may sound silly. Is it mandatory to mention the file extension in php `header()` function?
For example,

```
header('Content-Type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename:"testfile.pdf"');
```

The code which I was using earlier was not having the extension. But worked fine.

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename:"testfile"');
```

But now the same code does not work the same way it was working before. The browser is showing that the file type is unknown and prompting to select the application to view the file.

I made no code changes which handles this part. But yet it acts differently. I'm using HTMLDOC plugin to render the content into a PDF file.

Comment: Probably not mandatory but it helps the browserunderstand what is coming down the wire

Comment: It is up to the browser/OS to decide how to handle this. It might be configured to automatically suggest `.pdf` as extension when saving files of content-type `application/pdf` – or it might not. If you want to make sure that `testfile.pdf` is suggested, then include the file ending in the `filename`.